# Making a custom responsive component

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a custom Navigation Bar for a website.
The idea is to create , like a pie chart with the different section of the website, expanding on hover, with a image in the background forming part of the chart itself.
Let me clarify with some images:

[image: idea form]

And then with the hovering effect on one of the parts:
[image]

The hovering spread the spiral to the exterior and show the label "Home".
Note that the 'spiral' is representative, normally it would be a logo, or a image.
My question is which technology should i use?
Pure css?
JS?
HTML CANVAS? or SVG?

Another thing is the spiral on the background, if its an image, how can i modify it while hovering? do i need to 're-create' the image with code ? like svg drawings etc..

Thank you very much , any ideas is welcome

Comment: I would definitely approach this via SVG's, using javascript onclick handlers like so: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/onclick
Beyond the rudimentary concepts, you will have to begin dabbling in the design aspect and the implementation on your own. If needed you can bring a more reproducible example in a new question based on your findings, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend finding an svg file and uploading it to figma, assigning each section an id, and using event handlers to manage the click events.
This video shows you how to import into figma and assign ids to different sections.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gWai7fYp9PY&ab_channel=DevEd